# Implement facebook authentication

Tags: facebook

How many methods to implement facebook authentication on my website? My approach are:

1. Display a facebook login button on my website
2. When user click on it, they will be asked for username password or grant some permissions etc...
3. After they logged, display their face and name on my website at position of login button.

Now, I can do 1, 2 with this code below

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
        FB.init({ 
            appId:'22***00**58****', 
            cookie:true, 
            status:true, 
            xfbml:true,
            oauth:true
        });
    </script>
    <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
```

I'm still stuck with 3.

Answer (score 1):

check out the guide at http://fbdevhub.com/wiki/index.php?title=Canvas_App_Tutorial for a quickstart example

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JS SDK method you'll need to use.

```
FB.login(function(responseLogin) {
    if (responseLogin.session) {
        // user is logged in
        // uid is in responseLogin.session.uid
        // just explore the whole object with console.log(responseLogin);
    } else {
        // refused to grant the permissions
    }
}, { perms:'offline_access,email' }); // example of perms
```

Remove the <fb:login> button, replace by a real button, and when the user clicks on this button, call this method.
It's not the only way, but it's a simple one.